# Can't attach 2 networks to container in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I need to attach 2 networks to container and for one network I need static IP.
This is my docker compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  # --------------------------------------------- Web app container
  webapp:
    networks:
      br0:
          ipv4_address: 172.16.238.10
      - bridge
    container_name: homer-webapp
    build: ./webapp/.
    image: sipcapture/homer-webapp
    restart: always
```

But it doesn't work:

```
ERROR: yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 6, column 7
expected <block end>, but found '-'
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 8, column 7
```

If I just attach one network it works as expected.

If I attach 2 networks in following ways it works too:

```
networks:
  - br0
  - bridge
```

This doesn't work:

```
networks:
  - br0:
    - ipv4_address: 172.16.238.10
  - bridge
```

Error message I get:

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.webapp.networks contains {"br0": [{"ipv4_address": "172.16.238.10"}]}, which is an invalid type, it should be a string
```

Any hints? Any help are welcome!!!

Comment: Did you read this? https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#ipv4_address-ipv6_address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
version: '2'
services:
  # --------------------------------------------- Web app container
  webapp:
    networks:
      br0:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.238.10
      bridgeCUSTOM:
    container_name: homer-webapp
    build: ./webapp/.
    image: sipcapture/homer-webapp
    restart: always
networks:
  br0:
    external: true
  bridgeCUSTOM:
    external: true
```

Still don't know how to use br0 with default bridge instead of bridgeCUSTOM, but this is not big deal for me. Thank you all for help!